# Does Xcode install the “gcc” alias automatically or do I have to install command line tools?

Tags: xcode, gcc

I'm writing a tutorial for running GCC commands. After Xcode is installed on a mac, do the command line utilities have to be installed to get access to the gcc command that is aliased to the clang compiler? Or is installing Xcode the only step necessary?

Comment: try testing by compiling a c file ?//  also `which gcc` //  also, `gcc --version`.

Comment: I already have it installed. I'm asking how to get it installed if it's not already.

Comment: installing command line tools and changing the path via `xcode-select` is enough. some people also use brew's gcc.

Comment: I'm asking if installing xcode installs the command aliases for gcc.

Comment: yes. If it doesn't work for some reason, `xcode-select` should be used to reset its path

Comment: Although it does not really install gcc - it installs clang and then lies by linking gcc to that - So do not use a gcc tutorial the command lines are different